# Choosing different features from train and test sets for Random Forest

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, data-science

Should I choose only the important features from the train set and use those for predictions or create columns with 0 values for the features not included?

The training set and test sets have 6160 and 4000 features respectively.

Comment: First, I suggest you seek help from more relevant stack exchange sites such as https://stats.stackexchange.com/. Second, you should never have different features for training and testing, otherwise it's meaningless

Answer (score 0):

Using just the relevant features that actually have an impact on your prediction is the way to go. 
Using unnecessary feature columns just doesn’t help, rather increases your training time and complexity.

And having inconsistent features and training and test sets just doesn’t work. 
So either drop the columns from your data set that doesn’t correspond to both test and training sets, or try to fetch different data.

Don’t add feature columns with 0 values, as that is a feature value itself, and would be treated as bad data, leading to an inaccurate model.